# Basic statistics in R?

Tags: json, r, matrix, nested

I have statistics of different players. I would like to find out how to manipulate my data. How can I find:

- The matrix that has the highest "wins" count?
- The line in matrix that has best "wins" to "losses" ratio?
- How to compare values of "wins" in columns across all three matrices?

  ```
  library(jsonlite)
  iris2 <- fromJSON("C:\\Users\\Saonkfas\\Desktop\\WOWPAPI\\wowpfinaljson.json")
  print(iris2)
  for (x in iris2){print (x)}
  ```

This is what I have after printing:

```
   wins losses max_killed battles plane_id max_ground_object_destroyed
1  118     40          7     158     4401                           3
2  100     58          7     158     2401                           3
3  120     38          7     158     2403                           3
  wins losses max_killed battles plane_id max_ground_object_destroyed
1   12    450          7     158     4401                           3
2  150      8          7     158     2401                           3
3  120    328          7     158     2403                           3
  wins losses max_killed battles plane_id max_ground_object_destroyed
1  158     40          7     158     4401                           3
2 1010    584          7     158     2401                           3
3  120    348          7     158     2403                           3
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `How to compare values of "wins" in collumns accross all three matrixes`?  Do you want to find the row that has most wins across all three matrices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The data frame including the highest value of `wins`:

   ```
   iris2[[which.max(sapply(iris2, function(x) max(x$wins)))]]

     wins losses max_killed battles plane_id max_ground_object_destroyed
   1  158     40          7     158     4401                           3
   2 1010    584          7     158     2401                           3
   3  120    348          7     158     2403                           3
   ```
2. The rows with the highest `wins` to `losses` ratio of all data frames:

   ```
   lapply(iris2, function(x) x[which.max(x$wins / x$losses), ])

   [[1]]
     wins losses max_killed battles plane_id max_ground_object_destroyed
   3  120     38          7     158     2403                           3

   [[2]]
     wins losses max_killed battles plane_id max_ground_object_destroyed
   2  150      8          7     158     2401                           3

   [[3]]
     wins losses max_killed battles plane_id max_ground_object_destroyed
   1  158     40          7     158     4401                           3
   ```
3. This is too unspecific...

   > How to compare values of "wins" in collumns accross all three matrixes?